# Nginx php-fpm getting rid of 502 error on high traffic site

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, php-fpm, haproxy

currently i have a server with following specs:

```
32 core
128gb RAM
1TB SSD hardisk
5Gbps network uplink
```

current setup are nginx+php-fpm without any load balancing setup

**nginx.conf**

```
fastcgi_connect_timeout 9000;
fastcgi_send_timeout 9000;
fastcgi_read_timeout 9000;
fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;

fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;


    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)
    {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi-56.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        include pathinfo.conf;
    }
```

**php-fpm.conf**

```
[www]
listen = /tmp/php-cgi-56.sock
listen.backlog = -1
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
listen.mode = 0666
user = www
group = www
pm = static
pm.status_path = /phpfpm_56_status
pm.max_children = 2000
pm.start_servers = 40
pm.min_spare_servers = 40
pm.max_spare_servers = 300
request_terminate_timeout = 9000
request_slowlog_timeout = 0s
slowlog = var/log/slow.log
```

no matter how i change the config, i still getting 502 error with php-fpm, the ram usage on the server are arround 12-15GB max, we have plenty of RAM, but CPU usage for php-fpm is high. If you have any idea with the config, please suggest or comment.

Otherwise, im thinking of setting up load balancing like below, may need your idea:

**1) Using HaProxy**

[image]

**2) Using Nginx and multiple server as PHP-FPM pool:**

[image]

**3) Use current server with multiple php-fpm pool**

```
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:9001       max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server 127.0.0.1:9002     max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server 127.0.0.1:9003     max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}
```

which one do you think more suitable? i just need to get rid the 502 problem.

Comment: 502 means bad gateway. That means your PHP server probably can't handle the load. Look in your PHP error logs for messages.

Comment: Can't find much of error log, but we have slow log that more than 3s.

Comment: You need to either optimise the application or add more PHP-FPM workers. Your PHP-FPM log file tells you why the 502 error code is returned.

Comment: `we have plenty of RAM, but CPU usage for php-fpm is high` Been there. In most such situations (that I encountered), optimizing the application helped to reduce the CPU usage. Any kind of (fragment) cache at the application level helps to reduce the CPU usage. Good luck!

Comment: just enabled the debug log at php-fpm.conf, lets see if we cache anything.

Comment: I guess most of the requests don't need to get rendered again and again. If that's the case, you might want to introduce caching. I'm not sure if your approach ("lets see if we cache anything) will yield something useful, as it's too late if the requests hit your backend. Introduce caching before your backend, in `Nginx`. You can't copy / paste this, but to give you an idea how this could look like in detail see [this link](https://deliciousbrains.com/microcaching-wordpress-nginx-improve-server-requests-2400/).

Comment: Sorry, got confused by "cache". Should this have been "catch"? ;)

Comment: pm.max_children = 2000 + redis seem solved the problem